# Java EE Request scope and Asynchronous

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous

I am attempting to time an log performance using an interceptor.

```
@LogPerformance
@Interceptor
public class PerformanceInterceptor {
```

The times are stored in a request scoped bean.  When the the request has finished the times are written to a log file.

When I changed several of the logged methods to be asynchronous, the logging for those operations stopped being output.

```
 @Asynchronous
 @LogPerformance
 public Future<String> getString()  {
```

I believe the new EJB thread is defining a new request scope.  I can log output from the interceptor and see the request scoped object, but there are two different addresses attached to the objects.  One address for the http thread and a different address for the EJB thread.

Is there a way to allow the interceptors from the async methods to write to the object in the http request scope? Is there another way to get the data back into the parent scope?

Answer (score 1):

The container will propagate the [javax.ejb.EJBContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html) to the thread that executes the asynchronous method.

You can inject this EJBContext into your interceptor and stash any state (such as your request scoped bean) that you want into it via [javax.ejb.EJBContext.getContextData()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html#getContextData--).

Comment: I tried injecting the the EJBContext into the interceptor (both @Resource and @Inject).  It is failing when the container starts (missing dependency).  I believe the reason is the interceptor is a CDI Bean and therefore does not have an EJBContext associated with it.

Comment: I would expect that the lifecycle of an interceptor declared on an EJB method would be controlled by the EJB container.

Comment: Can you please include a code snippet showing how you exactly did this. I failed accessing stored contextData values from an @Asynchronous method with Payara, Wildfly, TomEE and Websphere Liberty Profile. (Even without using an interceptor)